# Laravel passing value from input to method get

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Im working on laravel app where i need to pass value from input field to URL, using get method

here is few lines of code, so you can look into that

```
Route::get('/addpoints/{id}/{p1_id}/{p2_id}/{points1}/{points2}', 'MatchController@addPoints')->name('addpoints');

@foreach ($match as $i) 
{{ $i->player1 }}
{{ $i->player2 }}
<input name="points1">
<input name="points2">
<a class="t" href="{{ url('addpoints/ ' . $i->id . '/' . $i->player1_id . '/' . $i->player2_id . '/' . POINTS1. '/' . POINTS2 )}}">Add points</a>
@endforeach
```

and also i know function need to be like

> public function addPoints($id, $p1_id, $p2_id, $points1, $points2){

So my question is how can i pass **POINTS1** and **POINTS2** properly

Comment: Passing value from input to method? That's what a `HTML form` is used for

Comment: can't use form, need to do it with a href

Comment: what is improper about it currently?

Comment: cant pass <input name="points1">
<input name="points2">
<a class="t" href="{{ url('addpoints/ ' . $i->id . '/' . $i->player1_id . '/' . $i->player2_id . '/' . POINTS1. '/' . POINTS2 )}}">Add points</a>

values from this two inputs

Answer (score 0):

Pass the values from your controller to your view:

```
public function addPoints($id, $p1_id, $p2_id, $points1, $points2) {
    // controller stuff

    return view('your-view', compact('match', 'points1', 'points2'));
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<a class="t" href="{{ url('addpoints/ ' . $i->id . '/' . $i->player1_id . '/' . $i->player2_id . '/' . $points1 . '/' . $points2 )}}">Add points</a>
```

Comment: hm not helping
it is throwing error like $points1 is not defiend